# How to make closure have its own copy of variable -does groovy have lambda

Tags: groovy, closures

What is the command in groovy to ensure a class variable is unaffected by a closure? As we know a closure captures the environment that its wrapped in. So, if I have a closure that increments an integer class variable for example, then that variable is changed for the class. What I want is for a closure to have its own copy of  a variable so it does not affect the class variable. Is it possible? In Objective C for example we would use the __Block command and that would make the block be able to change the value of a captured variable. Now, I am asking for the opposite of __Block in my case as closures are already changing the variables they are scoped in.

Lets take a look at a clear example of what I want:

```
def class myCoolClass {
    def x=1

    def myMethodThatReturnsClosure(){
        //lets return a closure who's scope will include the x=1
        myClosure
    }

    def showMeXFromMyCoolClass(){
        println "this is x from myCoolClass:$x"
    }

    def myClosure={
        println "im printing x:$x"
        //lets change x now from within closure
        x++
    }

}


def x = new myCoolClass();

def c=x.myMethodThatReturnsClosure();
c(); //we are changing x ...x = 1
c(); //we are changing x again  ...x = 2
c(); //we are changing x again ...x = 3

x.showMeXFromMyCoolClass(); //...x = 4
//i dont want x to be 4 in the last call, i want x to be 1. 
//i want it unchanged. how to tell closure to take its own copy
```

I realize in groovy a closure knows about its environment. It "closes out" around the function that its wrapped in. Is there lambda in groovy then? I think lambda would not know about its environment right? But lets say I want only want variable to not know about its environment and others should, then lambda would not be good.

Comment: Writing code this way will be impossible to debug, and future you will hate you now. Why not pass a parameter to a method that returns a closure?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, its just an example of what i want to do, i made it up. and it runs fine on Groovy Version: 2.4.1 JVM: 1.8.0_45 with just a cut and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code is not valid Groovy syntax. You may want to debug it and update the example with the fixes. Nevertheless, you got your point across.

One way of making the closure use a copy of the class variable is to make a copy of the variable and use it instead of `x` in the closure.:

```
def myMethodThatReturnsClosure() {
   def myX = x

   {
       println "im printing x:$myX"
       myX++
   }
}
```

This assumes the variable is a primitive, which grooy handles differently so that a copy is made. Otherwise the new variable would just be a reference to the original. In the latter case, you'd have to clone the object to get a copy.

Comment: BTW im using Groovy Version: 2.4.1 JVM: 1.8.0_45 and it works fine with a cut and paste.  I was hoping there was a commend like in objective c to define the scope of the closure. i see now there is not.